# Node is showing up as a Peer in Ethstats

Tags: private-blockchain, nodes

I am experimenting which Blockchains in a private environment.

I have created two nodes and they are showing up just fine in the ethstats page. One is local on my pc, the other one is also local but in a vm on my pc. I can see that they function well because at mining turned off they both ahve the same best block, and the blockminers are visible.

[image]

What is confusing me is that my node 2 is showing up as a peer and not as a separate node:

[image]

It is very clear that i am confusing the concept of nodes and peers. I have tried to look up existing questions which made me understand that a node can be a collection of peers. Am I understanding this well?

So how do i define a node and not a peer? Where is the distinction made?  What should I do?

to create the so-called peer, I:

1. ran the genesis file
2. took the ip of the 1st node + enode
3. hooked them with the geth command
4. waited for import
5. started mining on both

   ```
     geth --networkid 46851 --port 30303  --rpc   --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir "c:\\chain\\data-dir" --minerthreads 1 –bootnodes "enode://123456@192.168.40.10:30303"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Peers and nodes are the same thing, from one another's perspective.

Every machine running geth is a node. When one node connects to another, they become peers of each other.

Ethstats can only show a node in the list if it is reporting its statistics to ethstats. Make sure you have passed the ethstats config to both the geth commands.

Even if a node is not reporting statistics to ethstats, it can still show it as a miner and peers, as long as *any* node connected to ethstats is receiving the mined blocks, and is using this other node as a peer.

Comment: I still dont understand. when I connect an additional node to the blockchain network do I ALWAYS have to specify an enode? Why is that? I should have the networkid as an identifier no? Also

Comment: what do you mean by this? "Ethstats can only show a node in the list if it is reporting its statistics to ethstats. Make sure you have passed the ethstats config to both the geth commands." 

I am launching, as I said,  eth intelligence on both nodes. in fact they can see each other as I mentioned in the question. both because both miners are visible and because they see each other as peers.  But they are never listed as 2 nodes on the ethstats page.